# Remove ActionBar shadow programmatically at runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The ActionBar shadow can be removed with themes and the `windowContentOverlay` tag, but is it possible to dynamically remove and re-add it from code at runtime?

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922078/remove-action-bar-shadow-programmatically), which has not gotten any solving answers.

Comment: why don't you create and use a custom action-bar? then you can do any thing you want with it

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what you mean by custom action bar, but the alternative would be to just remove the shadow from themes, and then add a custom shadow manually the places I need it. But this is just not very convenient, and there should be a way to remove the default one programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a while, I was able to write a solution for API > 21:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle instance) {
    // ...

    actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setElevation(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setElevation(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation)); //8dp
    }
}
```

Hope this answer can help you by somehow, although have some while you asked that :